# Como criar um .JAR para a automação de testes?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Olá, estou criando scripts automatizados utilizando o Selenium WebDriver e estou executando dentro da IDE IntelliJ.
Gostaria de saber como é possível criar um arquivo .JAR dos meus scripts, dessa forma não seria necessário ter que abrir a IDE e executar o script.

Pesquisei bastante e não encontrei nenhuma solução, o mais próximo que cheguei foi que disseram que é necessário ter a classe "main", porém nos meus scripts não tem a classe main.

Meus scripts foram criados no caminho : src/test/java

Abaixo segue o script bem básico, apenas para abrir o navegador, como consigo gerar um .JAR desse script ?

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AbrirNavegador {
    private WebDriver navegador;

    @Test
    public void abrirNavegador() {

    //Abrindo o navegador

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Cesar\\Documents\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver navegador = new ChromeDriver();
    navegador.manage().window().maximize();
    navegador.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        navegador.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: Você quer executar o jar gerado, ou quer utilizar este jar em outros testes?

Comment: Ou você quer sempre executar este teste, independente do módulo em que ele esteja?

Comment: Quero sempre executar esse teste, é que tenho diversos scripts que nunca vão ser alterados, então sempre vão ser executados da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo você utilizar a estratégia de implementar os testes em um módulo comum, e executar uma suite padrão por módulo utilizando `@Suite`:

```
// Teste padrão - NOTE que a classe é abstrata
public abstract class AbstractAbrirNavegadorTest {

    private WebDriver navegador;

    @Test
    public void abrirNavegador() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Cesar\\Documents\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver navegador = new ChromeDriver();
        navegador.manage().window().maximize();
        navegador.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        navegador.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Nos submódulos que você deseja executar sempre o teste, inclua o jar comum como dependência e crie uma classe concreta para o teste:

```
// Implementação do teste padrão em todos os submódulos necessários
public class AbrirNavegadorTest extends AbstractAbrirNavegadorTest {

}
```

Ainda no submódulo, crie uma suite de testes executando a(s) classe(s) concreta(s):

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  AbrirNavegadorTest.class
  // Inclua aqui os testes padrões a serem executados
})
public class TestesPadroes {
    // Executa a suite com todos os testes padrões
}
```

Comment: Mas esse procedimento irá gerar o arquivo .JAR ?

Comment: Eu imaginei que pudesse ser algo um pouco simples, procurando pela IDE eu vi que tem a opção de "Build", que pelo o que eu pesquisei seria para criar o executável correto ?

Comment: Não, este procedimento cria um teste reutilizável para ser reaproveitado em N módulos. A criação do JAR depende de como você está fazendo seu empacotamento hoje (maven, gradle...)

Comment: Meu empacotamento está sendo em maven.

Comment: Então você deve gerar um `test-jar` deste módulo